# lxml: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, django, lxml

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.
It has running `Python27 x86 + Django 1.3 + apache 2.2 x86 under wsgi`. It runs ok without lxml.

We're using soaplib, which requires lxml. I tried installing lxml in several ways:

1. using easy_install
2. downloading win32 installation binary.

Problem is that running under site under apache raises following error:

```
ImportError at /
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It raises this error on `from lxml import etree`

I have googled for solution but found nothing useful. Some info I found:

1. That there was some change in python26->python27 that changes what dlls are included
2. I used dependency walker to find which dlls are missing. The ones I found missing are: gpsvc.dll, IEShims.dll, msvcr90.dll. When I tried installing x86 redistributable package but it didn't change anything. I tried copying msvcr90.dll to egg dir of lxml and it created another error that said it coudn't load the dll (I don't remember exact exception but I can generate it if needed)

It works when running from django internal server by running `manage.py runserver`

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I installed unofficial builds from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

It solved my problem.

Comment: For windows: I went to the lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml site (that person deserves a medal !) and there are a number of possible downloads for lxml. I have 32-bit Python 3.6. I saw there was a version 4.0 of lxml, lxml‑4.0.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl. So, I thought "new version, I'l have that one", installed it and still got the error. I then installed the 3.8 version, lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl, that works like a charm. I have no idea what the situation is for 64-bit Python, your miles may vary.

Comment: worked for me (win10 x64, python 3.6): 
1:  pip uninstall lxml
2: dwnd this lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
3: pip install "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

Comment: for windows, you need visual studio 2015. But it could work with visual studio 2017 if you follow these steps: https://dimitri.janczak.net/2017/05/20/python-3-6-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem as well when attempting to load etree via Windows Scripting Host. After trying different approaches, I came across this Python 3.1 change, which proposes that the new Python modules should no longer embed manifests as it causes distribution problems with no MSVC++ runtimes installed:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.lxml.devel/5684
- http://bugs.python.org/issue4120

So I've simply loaded up %PythonPath%\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.pyd in Resource Hacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and removed the manifest resource embedded in it.

Comment: Remove the embedded manifests by "Resource Hacker" works for me. I use activestate python 2.7.2, running python.exe script.py works well without any modification to the lxml package, while when I try to load python script inside vim script, I got the same error. After removing the manifest it works well.

Comment: I'm not sure from your description which part of the XML that appears for this file in Resource Hacker is the "manifest resource". Is that the attribute "manifestVersion"?

Answer (score 2):

Installing the DLLs isn't enough, you will need to fiddle Apache to use them. See:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/msg/afb025dc949c7051

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:
Step 1: pip uninstall lxml Step
2: pip install lxml

However, while re-installing lxml through lxml-4.6.3.tar.gz, I faced problems.
So, I tried the re-installation through the corresponding .whl file and succeeded!