# Cannot import etree from lxml: ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, lxml

I downloaded the lxml library from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5 for python26 on windows 64 bit. And installed it using the installer (.exe).

I can import lxml, but when I say `from lxml import etree`, it throws
exceptions:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I can see the etree.pyd in lxml folder under site-packages. I also included this path in pythonpath, but of no use. I tried googling it over the internet but could not find anything useful.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7228229/866026