# from lxml import etree ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have been trying to use etree as I want to start webscraping and have tried many different things, none of which have worked. Could someone please help.

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: did lxml install correctly?, is it for windows?

Comment: these are the requirements mentioned on the website **Unless you are using a static binary distribution (e.g. from a Windows binary installer), you need to install libxml2 and libxslt, in particular:**

Comment: For Windows go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lxml: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228229/lxml-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) (although I have the same problem and no answers from there work)

Comment: For windows: I went to the  lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml site (that person deserves a medal !) and there are a number of possible  downloads for lxml. I have 32-bit Python 3.6. I saw there was a version 4.0 of lxml, lxml‑4.0.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl. So, I thought "new version, I'l have that one", installed it and still got the error. I then installed the 3.8 version, lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl, that works like a charm. I have no idea what the situation is for 64-bit Python, your miles may vary.

Comment: it might be because you need visual studio 2015. But it could work with visual studio 2017 if you follw these steps: https://dimitri.janczak.net/2017/05/20/python-3-6-visual-studio-2017/