# lxml - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

**EDIT:**
this seems to be the actual problem:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

with:

`from lxml import etree
with open('C:\\Users\\jelme\Desktop\\TestScript\\derpo.xml', 'rb') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)`

**any solutions for this??**

*original question:*

Goodday,
I am a novice in python. This is the direct problem:

In this code:

`import lxml as ET
 tree = ET.parse(filename)`

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'lxml' has no attribute 'parse'
```

Let me explain what I am trying to do.
I have written a program that (succesfully) does the following using ElementTree:

- opens a bunch of xml files
- changes some text in the files
- gets a certain element and its children from every file
- makes a new tree with all these elements
- writes the new tree to a new file

However, I've discovered that I need certain CDATA lines from the original files, which ElementTree does not support (right?). Therefore I want to change to lxml. I thought that could be done by simply changing the imported module, however, I get this error.

I am running on Windows and installed lxml by:

`pip install lxml`

Hope that's enough information! Help is appreciated.

Comment: According to the docs this should be your import statement: `from lxml import etree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `parse` exist in the module `etree` of the package `lxml`. You could use the code below  instead:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse(open(file_path))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
I get this error when using this:
`from lxml import etree`
`DLL load failed`
That's gotta be something with me incorrectly installing?

Comment: I think yes, but I can't help you with this, sorry

Comment: This is my code now:

`from lxml import etree as ET`
`filename = "C:\\Users\\jelme\Desktop\\TestScript\\derpo.xml"`
`tree = ET.parse(filename)`

and i still get the DLL error.

Comment: You should pass the file or file-like object to the function. I already changed the code. Could you try with it?

Comment: Thanks. I still get the error:

`from lxml import etree as ET`
`filename = "C:\\Users\\jelme\Desktop\\TestScript\\file.xml"`
`tree = ET.parse(open(filename))`

Comment: @Jelmer you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243768/4175590. it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

it shoud be something like this

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("doc/test.xml")
```

As described here `http://lxml.de/parsing.html`

Comment: I have edited the question. the DLL error seems to be the problem. Any solutions? Google does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The parse() function is used to parse from files and file-like objects.

So you need to pass a file object, not a file name to the parser:

```
from lxml import etree
with open('/path/to/file.xml', 'rb') as f:
    tree = etree.parser(f)
```

Comment: I did provide a path, not just a filename:


`#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os, sys
from lxml import etree


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#Later change this to sys.argv
filename = "C:\\Users\\jelme\Desktop\\TestScript\\file.xml"

#filename = sys.argv[1]

tree = etree.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()`

Comment: I have edited the question. the DLL error seems to be the problem. Any solutions?